# Using XAML in Holographic Space

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, directx, hololens

I'm currently trying to add some user interface into my Holographic application.
My whole application is written with DirectX and I won't use Unity.

The app main feature is to display a 3D Volume in the Holographic space and interact with gesture such as rotation and translation.

An idea to improve the interaction, is to create some floating windows, to add advanced manipulations, and features.

In a perfect world I would like to draw in my floating windows (which would be floating plane, or billboard) an interface written in XAML or directly renderer by some Windows.UI.XAML.UIElement.

So basically I want to renderer XAML Element into a Texture2D, and I tried to do the following :

```
await CoreApplication.MainView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
{
      RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
      await renderBitmap.RenderAsync(PanoramicImage);
      XamlPixel = await renderBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
});
```

The problem is, RenderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync is blocking undefinitly, and I'm not able to reach the GetPixelsAsync function.

Do you guys have any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue. What your `PanoramicImage`?   I tested with a Grid.  And may be more information about the environment.

Comment: My PanoramicImage is just a Grid too, but are you using it in a HolographicSpace ? (UWP with Hololens device)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i work for quite a while on my own uwp hololens application in directx.
We solved the "UI-Problem" with direct2d... you can render a selfmade texture to a rendertarget and then use it as a shaderressourceview for a ui element. I think even with the dispatcher there is "now" no way to render xaml controls in the holographic space. So i think you will need to write your own ui elements.

The way microsoft describes it, the only way to use xaml controls is to switch between holographic space and the normal mode:

[Microsoft Viewmodel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/design/app-model#Switching_views)

Comment: Without solution, I did the same thing... Thanks anyway :D